# Java Placing Tetris Like Blocks Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, libgdx, porting

So I've been working on this game, in java, I've gotten it working using python and pygame, but when I tried to port it to java using libgdx, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, it will compile, however when it runs pieces will overlap, and I'm not completely sure the reasoning  for that. I have `if (!ICERECTANGLES.contains(CURRENTRECT))` Which should prevent this from happening, however it does not appear to be stopping this incident.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;`

Map<Integer, int[][]> ICEBLOCKS = new HashMap<Integer, int[][]>();
Map<Integer, int[][]> PIECES = new HashMap<Integer, int[][]>();

private void iceBegin(){
    int PIECESADDED = 0;
    Random RANDOM = new Random();
    for (int x = 0; x < BOARDWIDTH; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < BOARDHEIGHT; y++){
            System.out.println( x + ", " + y);
            int LOOPNUM = 0;
            boolean FIT = false;
            while (!FIT){
                LOOPNUM += 1;
                if (LOOPNUM == 5) break;
                //Arrange the dictionary/array containing all of the pieces
                Map<Integer, int[][]> PIECESDICT = new HashMap<Integer, int[][]>();
                int[][] first = new int[][]{ {0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2}, {1,1} };
                PIECESDICT.put(1, first);
                int[][] second = new int[][]{ {0,0}, {0,1}, {1, 1} };
                PIECESDICT.put(2, second);
                int[][] third = new int[][]{ {0,0}, {0,1}, {1,0} };
                PIECESDICT.put(3, third);
                int[][] fourth = new int[][]{ {0,0}, {0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1} };
                PIECESDICT.put(4, fourth);
                int[][] fifth = new int[][]{ {0,0}, {1,0}, {2,0} };
                PIECESDICT.put(5, fifth);
                int[][] piece = new int[1][4];
                piece = PIECESDICT.get(RANDOM.nextInt(PIECESDICT.size()) + 1);
                int[][] PIECE = new int[piece.length][2];
                // fails in this for loop!!!!
                for (int i = 0; i < piece.length; i++){
                    PIECE[i][0] = piece[i][0];
                    PIECE[i][1] = piece[i][1];
                }
                //forward_backward determines whether the piece will be facing forward or backwards
                //also known as left or right
                boolean for_back = RANDOM.nextBoolean();
                if (for_back){
                    for (int[] P: PIECE){
                        if (P[0] > 0) P[0] = P[0] * -1; 
                    }
                }
                boolean PIECETRUE = true;
                // Makes sure that the block will fit without overlapping any other pieces
                for (int[] item: PIECE){
                    item[0] = item[0] + x;
                    item[1] = item[1] + y;
                    if (item[0] <= BOARDWIDTH && item[0] >=0){
                        if (item[1] <= BOARDHEIGHT && item[1] >= 0){
                            Rectangle CURRENTRECT = new Rectangle();
                            CURRENTRECT.x = item[0] * 50;
                            CURRENTRECT.y = item[1] * 50;
                            CURRENTRECT.width = 50;
                            CURRENTRECT.height = 50;
                            if (!ICERECTANGLES.contains(CURRENTRECT)){
                                PIECETRUE = PIECETRUE;
                            }
                            else PIECETRUE = false;
                        }
                        else PIECETRUE = false;
                    }
                    else PIECETRUE = false;
                }
                //then if piece fits add the rectangles to the rectangle array, and also add the PIECE to the PIECES array
                if (PIECETRUE == true){
                    PIECES.put(PIECES.size(), PIECE);
                    for (int[] item: PIECE){
                        Rectangle CURRENTRECT = new Rectangle();
                        CURRENTRECT.x = item[0] * 50;
                        CURRENTRECT.y = item[1] * 50;
                        CURRENTRECT.width = 50;
                        CURRENTRECT.height = 50;
                        ICERECTANGLES.add(CURRENTRECT);
                        ICEBLOCKS.put(ICEBLOCKS.size(), item);
                        PIECESADDED += 1;
                        System.out.println("New Piece Added: " + CURRENTRECT);
                    }
                    PIECES.put(PIECES.size(), PIECE);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In case you are wondering exactly what I want it to do here is the Python code that it is supposed to duplicate.

```
def randomPieces():
global PIECESPOS
POINTSTAKEN = []
PIECESPOS = {}
MovesAv = True
for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
    for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
        PIECESDICT = {1: [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [1,1]], 2: [[0,0], [1,0], [0,1]], 3: [[0,0], [0,1], [1,1]], 4: [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]], 5: [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0]]}   
        NUMTIMES = 0
        FIT = False
        while FIT != True:
            NUMTIMES += 1
            if NUMTIMES == 50:
                FIT = True
            piece = PIECESDICT[random.randint(1, len(PIECESDICT))]
            PIECE = []
            for item in piece: PIECE.append(item);
            for_back = bool(random.randint(0,1))
            if for_back:
                for item in PIECE:
                    if item[0] > 0: item[0] = item[0]*(-1);
            PIECETRUE = True
            for item in PIECE:
                item[0], item[1] = (item[0] + x), (item[1] + y)
                if item[0] <= BOARDWIDTH and item[0] >= 0:
                    if item[1] <= BOARDHEIGHT and item[1] >= 0:
                        if item not in POINTSTAKEN:
                            if PIECETRUE:
                                PIECETRUE = PIECETRUE
                        else:
                            PIECETRUE = False
                    else:
                        PIECETRUE = False
                else:
                    PIECETRUE = False
            if PIECETRUE:
                PIECESPOS[len(PIECESPOS)] = PIECE
                for item in PIECE: POINTSTAKEN.append(item)
                FIT = True
```

I would appreciate any guidance and advice on how to manipulate the algorithm to allow for no overlapping and not every single coordinate taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[][] PIECE = {};
```

creates an array of size 0.

Hence these statements

```
PIECE[i][0] = piece[i][0];
PIECE[i][1] = piece[i][1];
```

will not work.

You might want to change

```
int[][] PIECE = {};
```

to

```
int[][] PIECE = new int[x][y];//eg. int[][] PIECE = new int[2][4];
```